# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified in FormView and SQL SERVER c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I have one stored procedure called `VideoGalleryDelete` . I am using `FormView` and `Gridview` to insert, update, show and delete data. `VideoGallery` is my primary table with PK `VideoId` and it has a foreign key as `CategoryId` .

When i click `Delete linkButton`, its says **Procedure or function has too many arguments specified**

This is my SP :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VideoGalleryDelete]
@VideoId int
AS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM [dbo].[VideoGallery]
      WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
      END
```

GridView and its assigned SqlDataSource :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVideo" CssClass="table" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVideo_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="VideoId,CategoryId" DataSourceID="sdVideoList">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoId" Visible="false" HeaderText="VideoId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="VideoId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoLink" HeaderText="Video Link" SortExpression="VideoLink" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryId" HeaderText="Category Id" SortExpression="CategoryId" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ID="lnkedit" Style="margin-left: 15px" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:ImageButton>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="Delete" Style="margin-left: 15px" runat="server" Width="20px" OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete();"></asp:ImageButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdVideoList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebAAERT_DBConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="VideoGalleryDelete" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="VideoGallerySelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="VideoId" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="CategoryId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: I believe this may be because you have both VideoId and CategoryId as DataKeyNames on your GridView, so it's trying to use both of them to identify the record to delete. You could maybe prove this by setting up your stored procedure to accept a CategoryId that you then ignore. However, that's not a good solution, so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: it doesn't matter that i have given two datakeynames. my delete parameter is Videoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misusing the [DataKeyNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the grid view control.This property should ideally contain only the primary key field(s) to identify the current row.Also every single value set on this property will be passed through to the Delete command.

Your delete stored proc takes one parameter but two values are being passed through beacuase of `DataKeyNames="VideoId,CategoryId"`.So you can do what @Chris Flynn suggested or change your grid view to `DataKeyNames="VideoId"`

Comment: i have given DataKeyNames. and as you can see i have set my Delete Parameter as VideoId

Comment: i need categoryId to Update the record.

Comment: Then use VideoId to look up the CategoryId